# How did Ganos Lal avoid the effects of the Sangraal?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

*(Spoilers for Season 10!)*

After the events of *[The Pegasus Project](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/The_Pegasus_Project)*, Ganos Lal (aka Morgan le Fay) is exiled from the Milky Way and Pegasus galaxies to the Ori home galaxy, due to her marginal intervention in the human-Ori war.

Half a season later, in *[The Shroud](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/The_Shroud)* SG-1 sends Merlin's device — the [Sangraal](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Sangraal) — through the second Supergate to the Ori home galaxy, and it is later confirmed by Ba'al (having taken Adria as a host) that this action was successful in wiping out the Ori. Recall that the Sangraal is a weapon that destroys *all ascended beings*.

But in *[The Ark of Truth](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate:_The_Ark_of_Truth)* we see that Ganos Lal was "alive" and well, chilling out in the Ori home galaxy. Good thing too, seeing as she was then instrumental in the defeat of the now-ascended Adria.

**How did Ganos Lal survive Merlin's device?** Did it take the Ancients a whole half season (six months in-universe, perhaps?) to get around to shipping her off to the Ori home galaxy, such that SG-1 had *already* killed the Ori by the time she arrived? Was this ever explained in dialogue or in production interviews?

Comment: Hmm, just notice Stargate Wikia asserts: _"She sent visions of the Ark of Truth to Dr. Daniel Jackson, and followed the Odyssey through the Supergate to the Alteran Home Galaxy, where she was able to act more freely as the Ancients were not there."_ If I can find this in dialogue, I guess that's that.

Comment: Not in the dialogue. And doesn't seem to fit the common definition of "exile" too closely if the "exile" part didn't actually involve her going anywhere. Maybe if we rely on the notion that even an ascended being would need a Stargate to travel that far in space (and we've seen them use gates before), then we can take it at face value?

Comment: I can't see anything in either that episode, nor in the film script that indicates that she traveled through the gate, nor that she was exiled to the Ori galaxy. It just says that she faced exile, then she pops up again talking to Daniel in AoT.

Comment: No help from the (awful) Director's Commentary on "Ark of Truth". Now, if you'd just asked a question about which lenses they'd used for every.damn.scene, I could answer those with ease...

Comment: No help from the Writer/Director commentary on "The Pegasus Project", although there's some fascinating chatter about how the Ori managed to fit the large supergate pieces through a standard sized Stargate. Answer, with great difficulty, it would seem

Comment: @Richard _" Now, if you'd just asked a question about which lenses they'd used for every.damn.scene, I could answer those with ease.."_ Heh (well that'd be too easy?!)

Comment: I swear, that commentary was the worst thing I've ever listened to. And I've listened to cats fighting. *"Oh well, in this scene we used a slightly wider lens then we did in the previous scene. And in the next scene, we used a slightly less wide lens. Hey, do you remember how we filmed this scene, we needed to take the wall back slightly because the camera wouldn't quite fit. That was hilarious. Oh, and in this scene we switched back to the original lens because the first lens was slightly wider"*

Comment: @Richard: I almost want to watch/listen to it now just for the sake of making me feel better/worse about my life

Comment: With the exception of repeatedly talking about the "richness" of the colours in the film format, I don't think they actually referred to anything that was happening on screen for at least the first 30 minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not especially clear that Morgan Le Fay was exiled to the Ori Galaxy. The only dialogue we have (from Morgan herself in Ark of Truth) is that she was exiled... erm... *somewhere*.

That particular somewhere may have been a specific planet (like Orin) or it may have been that she was held captive in a slightly lower plane of existence than the Ascended Ancients.

> **MORGAN LE FAY:** *Interfering with the lower planes is not allowed.*
>   **DANIEL:** *Yeah, I know. I did it myself more than once. Helping me is forbidden, and letting me know you're helping me, well, that's... worse.*
>   **MORGAN LE FAY:** *I did it once and they stopped me. **I was exiled for it.***

By the same token, it's not clear how she managed to travel to the Ori Galaxy (or even when). The supposition on the Wiki is that she traveled aboard the Odyssey, but I see no logical reason why she couldn't have stowed away on an Ori vessel, traveled through space under her own power or even just used a standard Stargate to travel to Celestis, given that she most certainly has the technical knowledge and wherewithal to do so.

Comment: I concur and, unless Brad Wright pops along to weigh in, this is probably the best we'll get.